# Копировать часть строки до и после символа

Tags: строки, c++

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как скопировать часть строки до пробела, и соответственно часть строки после, а после этого записать их в отдельные переменные? Например, есть строка "23 45". Вопрос: как записать первое число (23) в одну переменную, а второе число (45) в другую? Эти самые две переменные должны иметь тип int. Подскажите пожалуйста, заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать `stringstream`:

http://ideone.com/1T9dNh

Comment: **`stream`**`stream`

**`string`**`stream`

подправьте, дабы не путать

Comment: что в данном случае s?

Comment: `std::stringstream` -это поток данных (в принципе аналог `cout\cin`, только работает не с консолью а с буфером данных(строкой))

Comment: @SuperChiken, если в строке кроме 2-х чисел и пробела между ними ничего нет (и Вы уверены в таком форматировании строки), то самое простое (решается в одну строчку)

    int a, b;
    char *s = ...;
    sscanf(s, "%d %d", &a, &b); 

если строка это С++-ная string, то

    string s = ...;
    sscanf(s.c_str(), "%d %d", &a, &b); // в принципе то же самое

Если же у Вас есть адрес пробела между числами где-то посреди строки, то придется искать начало первого числа (анализировать символы строки в цикле), а потом так же - sscanf...

Comment: @avp: или `strtok`?

Comment: @VladD, IMHO `strtok()` лучше вообще не пользоваться, т.к. она "портит" строку-аргумент. 

Потом еще надо не ошибиться (а если это не один пробел между числами?) в цикле по ее результатам.

Т.е. запрограммировать, конечно, можно, но это получается решение из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно"

Comment: @avp: ну это да, и ещё потоконебезопасна вроде бы (по крайней мере, была).